# VBA Access Compile Error variable not defined

Tags: function, vba, compiler-errors, undefined

I have this script that I want to use to move folders for archive this is my code :

```
Public Function modbalsmovearhive()
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.MoveFile "H:\Credit_Bals*.xls", "H:\Bals_Archive\"

End Function
```

Now when I go to run it I get the Compile Error variable not defined. Can someone assist me with the best way to resolve  this error.

Comment: Add `Dim FSO As Object` before `Set ...` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have forgotten to dimension the object, I'm guessing using:

```
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
```

Also make sure that you have the reference checked for Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the code and it works. Make sure Option Explicit is not On, and also make sure have included all the libraries you are using in your code.

EDIT: It is NOT good practice to have Option Explicit Off, so if you do want to keep it on, make sure all your variables are declared and your libraries included.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that after putting define variable option OFF, existing module wouldn't change, that is, existing module will continue to have Option Explicit. In that case you need to copy code to a new module.